# Microphone Clipping unless gain is ridiculously low

Tags: microphone, xlr, clipping

So i've had an X1 S XLR microphone for a year or two now, and while it delivers clear audio, it seems exceptionally sensitive. It says it has a maximum SPL of 140/150/160 depending on switch setting, but I can't for the life of me get the audio to record at a reasonable level. Either the audio sounds fine at a normal talking volume, but when i raise my voice even slightly i get massive clipping. Or I can turn the gain down and avoid clipping, but the lower stuff is so massively low it can't be heard at all. I've tried recording audio that is louder at lower gain, but i can't normalize it to the speaking audio levels without a massive quality drop. Is my hardware not built for what im doing? or am i misusing it in some very obvious way that i don't understand?

Comment: "Is my hardware not built for what im doing?" We don't know, you didn't tell us what your hardware is. Are you certain it's the mic that's clipping, not your mic pre?

Comment: Sorry, i'm really new to this from a realistic standpoint. So i'm using an X1 S XLR mic, which i think i mentioned, and running it through a PreSonus Audiobox USB 96 directly into my PC. Lowering the gain on the Audiobox fixes the clipping, but the audio that actually comes through is so quiet it's completely unusable. I'm using Audacity for recording software.

Comment: You're running XLR to XLR, phantom on? That should be just fine. Check levels as they come into Audacity, aim to peak around -6 maximum. that should give you more than enough headroom on a controlled voice track. Live, or uncontrolled, such as if you're swinging a boom for dialog, you should peak -18 to be safe. If your mic & pre are OK, that should still give you a low enough noise-floor to be perfectly usable.